# Compute Recall and Precision to evaluate CBIR system

Tags: opencv, sift, confusion-matrix, precision-recall, cbir

I implemented a CBIR with SIFT combined with other feature-based algorithms (with OpenCV and Python3), now I have to evaluate how the combination of them (i.e. SIFT/SURF, ORB/BRISK...) perform.

I found that I can use Precision |TP| / (|TP| + |FP|) and Recall |TP| / (|TP| + |FN|). I know that the TP is the correct positive, that FN is the relevant documents that are not returned and that the FP is the documents that are returned but are not relevant

I calculate my matches with BF and I presume that:

- `matches=bf.knnMatch(descriptor1, descriptor2, k=2)` are my TP+FP
- the matches finded with ration test are my TP

How can I calculate my FN? Such as the matches that are relevant but not returned?

Note that I'm just formulating a hypothesis, so please correct me if I'm wrong.

I would like to have some help on the concrete implementation, such as where are these data in a concrete case of images matching.

In alternative can you please suggest me how to evaluate a CBIR system based on feature detection and description?

Comment: Hello, due to the nature of the problem, that can't be easily explained, you may have a look to this [dissertation](https://retbul.sniafas.eu/downloads/dissertation.pdf). Hope it helps.

Comment: @ Stavros Niafas Thank you for your dissertation. If I got you right, you just counted the number of relevant retrieved images on total relevant images and on total retrieved images?  Can I also ask you which kind of Plot did you use in Figure 13. pag. 37?

Comment: that's right. It's the Recall and Precision accordingly. If I got you right, it's not something fixed. Plots are custom made with matlab, iterating in every specific metric.
More specific, eg Precision, for 9 inliers threshold,
I got 3 relevant to the query image(from same house class) / all retrieved image above 9 threshold, lets say 5.
Precision(for class 1) = 3/5

Comment: @Stavros Niafas Thanks a lot! Now is clear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found an answer to my question, maybe it can help someone!

There is a difference between PRECISION and RECALL calculate in INFORMATION RETRIEVAL CONTEXT  and in CLASSIFICATION CONTEXT.

For information retrieval:

```
precision = (relevant documents + retrieved documents) / retrieved documents
recall = (relevant documents + retrieved dcuments) / relevant documents
```

For classification context, it is possible to speak about confusion matrix:

```
precision = TP/TP+FP
recall = TP/TP+FN
```

In my case, for example, was not possible to use the confusion matrix.